# Python changed Windows drive from C: to D: and broke windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, python

I installed bunch of python tools to run on windows command line and when i restarted the system C drive became D drive and D drive became C drive.

When the computer was restarting it was deleting 1000s of index files, I let it run until it finished and restarted again.

But after restart windows couldn't load. When I checked C drive I could only see HP recovery folder and System folder.

I thought I lost all the files but when i checked D drive, I found all the windows system files and my own files.

Because now windows is in D drive, it fails to load. Is there a way to restore back everything?

Thank you.

***UPDATE***: I sent my box to IT department and they couldn't fix it, so formatted and re-installed windows. :(

Comment: Whatever you try first make full image backups of the drives. Maybe then uninstall the Python stuff?

Comment: python shouldn't have done that. This is PRETTY odd.

Answer (score 0):

Try Restore MBR

[How to Restore the Windows 7 MBR](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/20864-mbr-restore-windows-7-master-boot-record.html)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.